# Active_support/dependencies.rb:247 `require': cannot load such file -- 2.1/pg_ext (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm using Ruby 2.1.5, Rails 4.1.6 and PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on a Windows machine.

When I try to `bundle exec rails server`, I end up with the following error:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.1/pg_ext (LoadError)
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in re...re'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependancy'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.17.1-x86-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:10:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.17.1-x86-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
 from C:/....../config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
 from bin/rails:8:in `require'
 from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 7):

I needed to use a newer version of pg gem:

`gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.0.pre20141117110243'`

Comment: i use such: `gem 'pg', '0.18.0.pre20141117110243'` because with gem pg 0.18.1 is was fallen

Answer (score 0):

After updating, sometimes happens.

Try remove all gems and install all again. like

```
rm -rf ./vendor/bundle
bundle install
```